# Writing to file cut off in C

Tags: c, file

I'm currently trying to learn how to code in C. I have some code that is supposed to generate a "password" out of random characters and save it to a file. It seems like the password that's written to the file is cut off.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char password[65536];
    char chars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-+={[]}\\|;:'\",<.>/?`~!@#$^&*()";
    int size;
    char path[512];
    printf("Where should the key be saved? ");
    fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdin);
    path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
    Sleep(500);
    printf("How long should the key be? (max 65535) ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    if(size >= sizeof(password)) {
        printf("Size is too large\n");
        return 1;
    }
    getchar();
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int choice = rand() % sizeof(chars);
        printf("%c",chars[choice]);
        password[i] = chars[choice];
    }
    password[size] = '\0';
    FILE* fptr = fopen(path,"w");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file for writing\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", password);
    fclose(fptr); 
}
```

Here is an instance of this issue:

Length inputted: 5000

Printed: bWe...Ux<.../[P

Saved to file: bWe...Ux<

I'm expecting it to write the entirety of the password, but as I tried to show above it cuts off at some point.

It also seems to cut off at a different point each time.

Comment: You need `fopen(path,"wb")` if you're writing binary. Otherwise you will get line terminator translation.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `94`.

Comment: @user3386109 That’s the amount of characters there are. I figured I needed it to do that or it would return an error saying that index didn’t exist.

Comment: use sizeof(chars) instead of 94 and why do you need to make a string out of it, instead just write character by character to the file.

Comment: That was a hint (as well as being good advice in general). 94 is the wrong number. You should use code to compute the number. That way, if you add or remove characters in the string, the code will still be using the correct number. Also, if you compute the number in the code, and the number is wrong, then people can tell you what's wrong with calculation.

Comment: @AndersK: `strlen`, not `sizeof` (see my answer). The size of `"abc"` is four, not three, it includes the terminating `\0`.

Comment: @user3386109 is correct. If you have *any* number in your code other than `-1`, `0`, or `1` (other than for initialising constants or as part of `#define`, it would probably be better as a symbol (constant or `#define`).

Comment: @user207421: I don't think binary files are an issue here, the intent is to write text only.

Comment: @paxdiablo well since he is doing modulo i.e. % on the size, then sizeof should be correct in this context. strlen would make it impossible to get the last character in the array.

Comment: @AndersK: using `% sizeof` for an `N`-character string will you values from `0` to `N` since the ***size*** of it is `N+1` characters. The string only has usable characters at indexes `0` through `N-1`. Index `N` holds the `\0` at the end of the string. Hence `strlen` is the correct operator here.

Comment: @paxdiablo you are right of course, bug in brain by me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only 93 useful characters in `chars` (indexes 0 thru 92 inclusive).

When use use `rand() % 94`, you will occasionally get the value 93, which is the index of the `\0` at the end of the string.

Since you're using `fprintf("%s")` to print it, that will stop at the end of the string, which is the *first* `\0` it sees.

It's therefore cutting off at random places since it randomly selects the `\0` on a roughly one-in-ninety chance :-)

You would be better off using `strlen(chars)` rather than the magic `94` value.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I just saw the length on vscode and used that.

Comment: @NicholasPicklas: if you used editor character positions, that won't account for the fact that both `<backslash><backslash>` and `<backslash>"` are a *single* character to C but *two* characters to the editor.